# vimでbracketsやbracesをオートインデントを有効にした状態で自動補完する

Tags: vim

vimでかっこなどを自動補完するdelimitmateというプラグインを使っているのですが、
jsなどで{}を入力して、改行した際に(例1)のようにオートインデントされた場所にカーソルを移動させたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか? 
また(例1)の状態で何か文字列を入力した後改行してもオートインデントが有効にしたいです。

改行しないときは (例2) のように通常通りのカーソルの位置にしたいと思っています。

例１

```
{
    | 
}
```

例2

```
{|}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vimrcで `let g:delimitMate_expand_cr = 1` を設定すればできると思います。
詳細は `:help delimitMateExpansion` をご確認ください。
`let g:delimitMate_expand_space = 1` も便利です。

Answer (score 0):

私はRubyを使う関係上vim-endwiseを使っていたのですが，そっち関連で以下のような記事があります．
参考までに．

[JavaScriptでもvim-endwiseのように補完する](http://alice345.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/03/01/232540)